# A general question regarding "exists" statement, about graph theory

Tags: real-analysis, graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a connected undirected graph. Let $s \in V$ be a vertex in the graph.

True/False: If $v$ is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from DFS(s), then $v$ is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from BFS(s) ($v \ne s$).

So by looking at the contra-positive, we get:

If there exists a spanning tree resulting from BFS(s) in which $v$ is not a leaf, then there exists a spanning tree resulting from DFS(s) in which $v$ is not a leaf.

---

Assume there exists a spanning tree generated from BFS(s) in which $v$ is not a leaf.

Then I need to show the existence of the second half of this statement?

If someone can give me some hints, I will very appreciate it!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why use the contrapositive? I'd rather investigate what the condition "is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from DFS" amounts to. That is: Given $s$ and $v$, what could prevent you from picking a specific DFS that does *not* make $v$ a leaf?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What do you mean by that? I need to prove it, I can't choose a specific DFS

Answer (score 0):

Extending the hint by Hagen von Eitzen:

Assume you are given $s$ and $v$ with $s \neq v$. Now imagine starting a DFS at $s$. Imagine the first time this DFS reaches $s$. What is true for the neighbors of $s$ at this point? How many of them have been visited already?

So what condition on the neighborhood of $s$ can you derive from that (assuming that $s$ is a leaf in every DFS-tree)? Once you have the condition, you will immediately see why this implies that $s$ is a leaf in every BFS-tree.